# getaddrinfo() blocks the application in android if no Internet

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I am using  **getaddrinfo()**  linux API in my android app (in C++ NDK). Everything works fine except for one case.

If there is no internet connection in the android system, this API blocks the application for more than 50 seconds.

Is there any resolution of this problem?

A lot of posts suggest to use this API in a thread. Is that the only solution? I guess there might be an easy or alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try using connection timeout as the value lesser than 50 seconds.
2. Also, you can check network before making any API. If there is no network do not proceed. If network goes away while executing API, connection timeout will come into picture.

Comment: int getaddrinfo(const char *node, const char *service,
                const struct addrinfo *hints,
                struct addrinfo **res); and  struct addrinfo {
    int              ai_flags;
    int              ai_family;
    int              ai_socktype;
    int              ai_protocol;
    socklen_t        ai_addrlen;
    struct sockaddr *ai_addr;
    char            *ai_canonname;
    struct addrinfo *ai_next;
};  So there is no option to set timeout. To check Internet connection in Android I need to check connection with another server which i never know if it is up or not .

Comment: Googling for "open source DNS library" reveals lots of async DNS libraries.  http://www.statdns.com/resources/

Answer (score 0):

[getaddrinfo()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getaddrinfo.3.html) is a blocking API, so this is expected. You'll probably want to do task in a worker thread and/or look into using [getaddrinfo_a(](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getaddrinfo_a.3.html)) which can perform asynchronous queries.